# IE Fixed Position Dialog, Slow Scrolling Div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have been working this problem for sometime now and haven't been able to figure out what is causing the issue. It is only happening in IE. We are testing with IE8.

I have a div that is positioned Fixed and centered on the screen (It is supposed to be a dialog). Inside that div there is a left and right section, both of those divs are floated left. Inside the Right box, I am dynamically loading (via ajax) images and some associated data. The right div is extremely slow when trying to scroll. We are limiting the images per page to 12. The layout looks like this....

The images are linked to Fancybox so that the user can see the full size.

(pseudo code)

```
<div id="popup_container" style="z-index: 99; top: 50%; left: 50%; height: 500px; width: 900px; position: fixed;" >
     <div class="left" style="float: left;">
     </div>
     <div class="right" style="float: left; overflow: scroll;">
        <div class="image" style="float: left;"><a href="fancy"><img src="data.jpg"/></a>Data Data Data</div>
        <div class="image" style="float: left;"><a href="fancy"><img src="data.jpg"/></a>Data Data Data</div>
        <div class="image" style="float: left;"><a href="fancy"><img src="data.jpg"/></a>Data Data Data</div>
        <div class="clearer" style="clear: both; height: 0px;"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearer" style="clear: both; height: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Can you link to a live example?

Comment: It's on an intranet currently. Perhaps I can setup a test page.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem one time and it ended up being an issue with the workstation. If you use a different workstation do you get the same results?

Comment: Yes, I have tried several computers and a few VMs. Same issue on all of them.